# Nesting apply in lapply to loop over columns of a list of matrices

Tags: r, hydrogof

I have a list of matrices, and I'm trying to apply a function to each column of each of the matrices.  The natural way to do that, I would think, is to nest `apply` in an `lapply`, but when I do that, it gives me an error:

```
library(hydroGOF)  # for the mse function

# Create a vector for comparison
A <- rnorm(10)

# Create a list of matrices to be looped over
B <- rnorm(10 * 5 * 3)
list.element.number <- rep(1:3, 50)
B.list <- split(B, list.element.number)
B.list <- lapply(B.list, matrix, ncol = 5, nrow = 10)  # A 3 element list of 10 x 5 matrices

# Wrapper function for mse
my.mse <- function(sim) {
  mse(sim, A)
}

# I'm trying to loop through each column of B.list and compare it to A
lapply(B.list, apply, MARGIN = 2, FUN = my.mse)
# Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
#   unused arguments (function (X, MARGIN, FUN, ...) 
#   {
#     FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
#     dl <- length(dim(X))
#     if (!dl) stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")
#     if (is.object(X)) X <- if (dl == 2) as.matrix(X) else as.array(X)
#     d <- dim(X)
#     dn <- dimnames(X)
#     ds <- seq_len(dl)
#     if (is.character(MARGIN)) {
#       if (is.null(dnn <- names(dn))) stop("'X' must have named dimnames")
#       MARGIN <- match(MARGIN, dnn)
#       if (anyNA(MARGIN)) stop("not all elements of 'MARGIN' are names of dimensions")
#     }
#     s.call <- ds[-MARGIN]
#     s.ans <- ds[MARGIN]
#     d.call <- d[-MARGIN]
#     d.ans <- d[MARGIN]
#     dn.call <- dn[-MARGIN]
#     dn.ans <- dn[MARGIN]
#     d2 <- prod(d.ans)
#     if (d2 == 0) {
#       newX <- array(vector(typeof(X), 1), dim = c(prod(d.call), 1))
#       ans <- FUN(if (length(d.call) < 2) newX[, 1] else array(newX[, 1], d.call, dn.call), ...)
#       return(if (is.null(ans)) ans else if (length(d.ans) < 2) ans[1][-1] else array(ans, d.ans, dn.a
```

Ideally, this would give me a 3 element list, where each element is a 5 element vector, but instead I get an error.  Does anyone know how to fix this (other than a `for` loop, which feels inelegant), or what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FUN=my.mse` is hijacking your attempt to `lapply` `apply`.  I think you want:

```
lapply(B.list, function(x) apply(x, 2, my.mse))
```

You can't specify `FUN` for both `lapply` and `apply` in the same call (unless you use positional matching as Konrad suggests).  What's happening is that your call is getting matched like so:

```
lapply(B.list, FUN=my.mse, ...=list(apply, MARGIN=2))
```

Which then in your first iteration leads to the attempt to evaluate:

```
my.mse(B.list[[1]], apply, MARGIN=2)
```

instead of your expected `apply(B.list[[1]], 2, my.mse)`.  Since `my.mse` only accepts one argument, you get the error about "unused argument".  If you look closely, the "unused argument" is the body of the `apply` function.

Comment: Positional arguments should work, though: `lapply(B.list, apply, 2, my.mse)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, great idea, though obviously you have to be mighty careful there.